# Unreliable Pandas Timestamp behavior. Almost the same input - different results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, jupyter

Everything is visible in the picture below but let me explain.

Lets create a Pandas timestamp object:

```
pd.Timestamp('2013, 11, 04') --> Timestamp('2013-11-04 00:00:00')
```

But, if you remove single space:

```
pd.Timestamp('2013,11, 04') --> Timestamp('2013-04-01 00:00:00')
```

To make it more bizzare:

```
pd.Timestamp('2013, 11,04') --> Timestamp('2013-11-01 00:00:00')
```

Now, what is this sorcery and who designed this behavior...
Any explanation that will not involve references to magical universe will be much appreciated.

**Apparently its a bug. Reported and acknowledged. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17265**

[image]

Comment: PEP standards are to put a space behind commas.  I guess the "intelligent" string parsing in pd.Timestamp uses PEP standards.

Comment: @ScottBoston I don't think PEP standards are created to regulate how strings of characters are created. PEP 8 -- Style Guide for **Python Code**

Comment: Not create, but I was thinking that PEP guide is maybe assumed when interpretting strings.  Just a guess.  Take it for what is worth.  If you put your string using PEP gets it right.

Comment: hmm, same problem with `print (pd.to_datetime('2013,11, 04'))`

Comment: This looks like a bug to me ...I see you've opened a GitHub issue and I think that's the right course of action.